# How can I change the sprite while jumping?

Tags: sprites, game-maker, jumping

```
///Initial Values

//Create the initial value of image_speed to use sub images
image_speed = 0.025;
grav = 0.5;
hsp = 0;
vsp = 0;
jumpspeed = 12;
movespeed = 3;
recently_hit = false;
counter = 0;
canshoot = true;
globalvar mpfacing;
mpfacing = 0;
```

are my initial variables

```
///Get player's input
key_right = keyboard_check(vk_right);
key_left = -keyboard_check(vk_left);
key_jump = keyboard_check_pressed(ord("Z"));
key_jump_held = keyboard_check(ord("Z"));

//React to inputs
move = key_left + key_right;
hsp = move * movespeed;
if (vsp < 10) vsp += grav;

if (place_meeting(x, y+1, Obj_Floor))
{
 vsp = key_jump * -jumpspeed;
}

if (vsp < 0) && (!key_jump_held) vsp = max(vsp,0)

//Horizontal Collision
if (place_meeting(x+hsp, y, Obj_Floor))
{
 while(!place_meeting(x+sign(hsp), y, Obj_Floor))
 {
  x += sign(hsp);
 }
 hsp = 0;
}
x += hsp;

//Vertical Collision
if (place_meeting(x, y+vsp, Obj_Floor))
{
 while(!place_meeting(x, y+sign(vsp), Obj_Floor))
 {
  y += sign(vsp);
 }
 vsp = 0;
}
y += vsp;

//Animate
if (move != 0) 
{
 image_xscale = move;
}

if (place_meeting(x, y+1, Obj_Floor))
{

 if (move != 0) 
 { 
  sprite_index = CalvinWalking;
  image_speed = 0.07;
 } 

 else 
 {
  sprite_index = CalvinStanding;
  image_speed = 0.025;
 }
}

else
{
 if (vsp < 0) sprite_index = CalvinJumping
 else sprite_index = CalvinJumping
}
```

is the main input

```
///Shooting with D
//Shooting direction
if (image_xscale = 1)
{
 mpfacing = 0;
}

if (image_xscale = -1)
{
 mpfacing = 180;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_up)) && (move = 0)
{
 mpfacing = 90;
 sprite_index = CalvinAimUp;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_up)) && (move != 0)
{
 mpfacing = 90;
 sprite_index = CalvinAimUpWalking;
}

//Aiming up and jumping
if (keyboard_check(vk_up)) && (keyboard_check(ord("Z")))
{
 mpfacing = 90;
 sprite_index = CalvinAimUpJumping;
}

//Shooting
if (keyboard_check(ord("X"))) && (canshoot = true) && (mpfacing != 90)
{
 instance_create(x+13, y-0.5, Obj_MP_Laser);
 canshoot = false;
 alarm[1] = 30;
}

if (keyboard_check(ord("X"))) && (canshoot = true) && (mpfacing = 90) && (image_xscale != -1)
{
 instance_create(x-10, y-26, Obj_MP_Laser);
 canshoot = false;
 alarm[1] = 30;
}

if (keyboard_check(ord("X"))) && (canshoot = true) && (mpfacing = 90) && (image_xscale = -1)
{
 instance_create(x+12, y-26, Obj_MP_Laser);
 canshoot = false;
 alarm[1] = 30;
}
```

and this is the script for shooting, (note each piece of code is in different scripts) and I can't figure out how to change the sprite in the ///shooting with D/// in //Aiming up and jumping// so the sprite will change until it is on the ground. And not how I set it up so it changes ONLY when I press the jump button (Z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to draw a jumping character *only* when the player presses the jump key, rather whenever he's **floating** in mid-air:

```
//Aiming up and jumping
if (keyboard_check(vk_up)) && (!place_meeting(x, y+1, Obj_Floor))
{
 mpfacing = 90;
 sprite_index = CalvinAimUpJumping;
}
```

You may want to use the `if (!place_meeting(x, y+1, Obj_Floor))` condition whenever you want to execute code if your character has no solid objects below his feet.

Comment: when i use the code it makes my sprite change to that always when i press up instead. However, I added a +1 to the y + vsp, and it worked, thank you.

Comment: That's right, since `vsp` is zero when executing this code. I edited my answers to include this.